# Decreasing accuracy of neural network after long training

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, adam

I trained a MLP network in Tensorflow which reached at some point 98.66 % accuracy. I used the MNIST data set and five hidden layers of the following size: 4096, 2048, 4096, 2048, 4096. In Tensorflow I used the Adam Optimizer to minimize the cost.

After a while the accuracy started to decrease until it reached about 11 % where the network got stuck.

[image]

[image]

[image]

What could be a possible reason for this behavior?